# Algorithm used by browser to detect visited URL by an user

Tags: algorithm, browser, data-structures

While I was going through Stackoverflow, i observed that what ever questions i have visited earlier those are marked by different color. Then i started thinking how stack overflow detects this.

Can somebody tell me what algorithm do they use, not only used by stackoverflow may be by different sites?

May be they are storing the question numbers in my cookie and after parsing the cookie data they are able to say the question i have visited. But if I have visited many questions is this approach possible?

**Update**

As everybody has mention this is a browser property, so question is how do they remember so many links, what algorithm or data structure do they use to store.

Comment: This happens on every other website too (though some decide to make the "visited" color the same as the "not visited" color so it can't be seen). Btw, do you really think we need a link to Stackoverflow? We're on it. Right now.

Comment: css `a: visited` maybe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, it's your user agent (e.g. browser), that is remembering visited links. Then a site can use [CSS](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#link-pseudo-classes) to style them to their liking.

> User agents commonly display unvisited links differently from previously visited ones. CSS provides the pseudo-classes ':link' and ':visited' to distinguish them.

---

As for your updated question. A glance at the [Chrome source](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/components/visitedlink/browser/visitedlink_master.h&sq=package%3achromium&l=391&rcl=1383398702) code brings up some kind of hash table as data structure.

Also, if your user agent is just interested, whether a link was visited or not, you'll only need to compute a *fingerprint* (e.g. [city hash](http://code.google.com/p/cityhash/source/browse/trunk/README)) of the URL and compare the cached fingerprints with the fingerprints of the links found on a page.

Even if you would visit one new URL every 10 seconds for a whole month and assuming the fingerprint would use up 40 bytes, you would consume only about 10 Megabytes of memory.

Comment: how do they remember? can you please give me some hint. thanks.

Comment: Probably has something to do with cookies

Comment: Just glanced at the [Chrome source](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/components/visitedlink/browser/visitedlink_master.h&sq=package:chromium&l=391&rcl=1383398702). It seems to be a hash table, that is occasionally persisted (depending on your settings).

Comment: Note that SO/SE does have views per question, which is a similar concept server-side.